# BotBuilder - FormFlow - how to change confirmation option language

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, botframework, formflow

I'm working with Microsoft Bot Framework facing with [FormFlow](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/forms.html).

I'm using confirmation dialog like this sample:

```
            return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
                    .Message("Welcome to the sandwich order bot!")
                    .Field(nameof(SandwichOrder.Sandwich))
                    ...
                    .Confirm("Do you want to order your {Length} {Sandwich} on {Bread} {&Bread} with {[{Cheese} {Toppings} {Sauces}]} to be sent to {DeliveryAddress} {?at {DeliveryTime:t}}?")
                    .AddRemainingFields()
                    .Message("Thanks for ordering a sandwich!")
                    .OnCompletionAsync(processOrder)
                    .Build();
```

Confirm dialog works but I'm running the bot then questions in italian language while Confirm seems to accept just "yes/no" options.

How to turn this into italian ("si/no")?

Is it possible to set language globally?

Thanks

Comment: The FormFlow builder does not yet support localization. We're planning to do so in a future update.  In the mean time you can change the BotBuilder source code yourself to change the confirmation prompt to Italian.

Answer (score 0):

The language is set in the dev.botframework.com website. You can edit your bot and set the Language parameter :

[Setting parameter for language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wyf0.png)

You can also ask the Bot Connector to translate automatically messages for you. This is done by the user. He only has to say : "I would like to speak spanish" and it will translate automatically message into spanish.

Comment: Hi Etienne, I know and it's already set in italian using country code "it", but doesn't works. More if I enable translation it translate all messages into english but not vice versa. May be I wrong something else? What could be?

Comment: I asked the team and there is a fix incoming for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look to the [AnnotatedSandwich sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot). With the latest release of the Builder package the sample was updated and now it shows how you can build a Localized Form. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot/AnnotatedSandwich.cs#L242) is the code where the form is being built.